# MYSQL get all id using parentid and id

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all `id` under a `typeid` using `id` i want to use just one query to do this it can be done with an inner query like this.

`SELECT id FROM users where typeId = (SELECT typeId FROM users where id = 5)`

This will give me what i want but i have heard that inner query is slow so i would like to do this using join query.

**users**

```
id typeid name
1  2      a
2  2      b
3  1      c
4  3      d
5  3      e
```

Comment: your query looks fine, it is true that in MySQL subqueries are often slower than JOINS but in your particular query I don't think it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be:

```
SELECT 
  a.id 
FROM 
  users AS a 
    LEFT JOIN users AS b 
      ON a.typeId=b.typeId 
WHERE 
  b.id = 5
```

-check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bead2/4).

Comment: @jay you're not correct in that. It will do exactly same thing, I've added fiddle to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

What you want I don't know with this query:

```
SELECT id FROM users where typeId = (SELECT typeId FROM users where id = 5)
```

You can simply write this query as:

```
SELECT t1.id 
     FROM users AS t1 
       LEFT JOIN users AS t2 
          ON t1.typeId = t2.typeId 
     WHERE t2.id=5
```

BUT I exclaimed that when you know id then why are you using the query to fetch the same id again. I think you are lacking some information.

Comment: actually i am not querying into a user table i just made the example simple. the real query would give all items in a category.

Comment: @jay check this query first this will return 4 and 5 both.